# How to start auditing smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, security

I want to become a smart contract auditor. I will report all the vulnerabilities which I have explored while auditing smart contracts.

Is there any platform available to learn how to audit smart contracts?

Is there any platform which will allow me to audit smart contracts developed by others?

Is there any platform where senior auditor share their experience and publish the vulnerabilities that they have found while auditing smart contracts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I am not affiliated with Solidified in any way.*

The best place to get started may be [solidified.io](https://www.solidified.io). They have all that you described above.

They have a platform for people to choose contracts to audit. They have many mentors on the site to help as well. Many companies use them for this kind of work.

You may also check out [gitcoin.co](https://gitcoin.co). This is not specific to auditing, but you can find a lot of good contract auditing work.

Answer (score 1):

To start auditing a smart contract, you will need to take the following steps:

1. Identify the target contract.
2. Check if it is available on Github or Etherscan. You can use Etherscan's API to query the contract's details. Alternatively, you can also use a tool like Truffle to find out more about your contract.
3. Read through the code and understand what it does from a high-level perspective. If possible, test out some of its features manually using truffle console commands or on the Ropsten testnet (if possible).
4. If there is an existing audit report for this contract, check that as well and see if there are any issues worth bringing up during your audit session later on down the line.